# How to clear install media list in virt-manager createvm page

Tags: virtualization, libvirt

There is an install media list in Virt-Manager createvm page.

[Create VM Page ISO/CDROM list UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJeKb.jpg)

Some media files were deleted but still shown in the list.

I have checked all the files located in `/etc/libvirt` and `/var/lib/libvirt` but there is not list.
Also, I have deleted all the files in `$HOME/.cache/virt-manager`, but nothing happened.

How to clear the list?

Comment: I also am wondering how to do this. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to clear the virt-manager media history list by using `gsettings` (dconf).

You can see what's in the list by using the `get` command:

```
gsettings get org.virt-manager.virt-manager.urls isos
```

And clear it by using the `reset` command:

```
gsettings reset org.virt-manager.virt-manager.urls isos
```